# A morphism in a category needs to bem well defined?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, morphism

We know from basic math that we have a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ if $x \in X$ maps to exactly one element in the codomain Y.

My question is that if we consider the morphism in categories as a generalization of function, a morphism had to be the condiction of well defined?

I don't know if this is a stupid question, but it raises when i'm reading about posets categories. If we see the partial order $\leq$ as a morphism in a partial ordered set, then a element in this set maps not necessary maps to just one element. In other words, if we have the set X={1,2,3,4) and the partial order $\leq$, we have that $1 \leq 2$ and $1 \leq 3$, etc.

The partial order above is a morphism? This morphism needs to be well defined?

Comment: short answer: everything in mathematics needs to be well-defined

Comment: Morphisms aren't functions in general. You are going up another level of abstraction....

Comment: I find this question pretty hard to understand, but from the context I think you're using the term "well defined" to mean "maps each element in the domain to exactly one element in the codomain", is that correct? (That's not what it usually means.)

Comment: Yes, i am using this term to describe that functipn. Sorry about that.

Comment: Half of your confusion has been explained by @AnginaSeng, but there's more. Your example about a partially ordered set indicates that you want a morphism in a category to be a function taking as inputs objects of that category and producing such objects as outputs. As Angina said, morphisms in a category need not be functions at all. Even when they are functions, for example in the category of sets, a morphism $f:A\to B$ doesn't take objects, like $A$, as inputs. Its inputs are the elements of the set $A$, and its outputs are among the elements of $B$.

Comment: The maps between categories are called **Functors**, and **morphisms are not Functors.** Functors have certain properties. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor

Answer (score 2):

While your question has been addressed pretty well in the comments, I wanted to address the question with examples, but also provide a possible way of seeing morphisms as functions as well.

First, as the comments have mentioned, the morphisms of a category certainly **do not have to be "functions"** like they are in the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of sets; all that's necessary is that the morphisms satisfy the appropriate axioms (i.e., they have an associative composition, and there exist identity morphisms).

- first, like the family of examples you mentioned, a poset $P$ can be viewed as a category whose objects are the elements of $P$, where there is a (unique) morphism $x\to y$ iff $x\preceq y$ in the partial order on $P$. If we wanted $x\to y$ to be a "function", then it would have to send "elements" of $x$ to "elements" of $y$... but what are "elements" of $x$?
- however, even if we *have* a readily-available notion of "element" (inherited from set theory), the morphisms *still* need not be functions. For example, consider the category [$\mathbf{Rel}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Rel) whose objects are sets, and whose morphisms $X\to Y$ are *relations* (i.e., the morphisms $X\to Y$ are the subsets of $X\times Y$). Despite the fact that $X$ and $Y$ actually *do* have elements, the morphisms are not functions of these elements.

  - for example, we always have the *empty relation* on $X\times Y$, which says that no $x\in X$ is related to any $y\in Y$. This is a morphism $X\to Y$ in $\mathbf{Rel}$, but how could this be seen as a function?

So, in summary, morphisms of a category are *not* functions in the naïve interpretation. However, there is a way to make them look like functions, and the way to do this is to rephrase what you mean by "elements."

To illustrate what I mean, consider $\mathbf{Set}$ (where the morphisms are precisely the functions of sets). Let $X$ be a set, then there is a natural correspondence between elements $x\in X$ and functions $\bar x:*\to X$ (where $*$ is a fixed choice of one-element set). If we think of elements as maps $*\to X$, then given a function $f:X\to Y$, "evaluation at $x$" translates to "composition with $\bar x$": the element $*\to Y$ corresponding to $f(x)$ is precisely $f\circ\bar x:*\to X\to Y$.

We can play a similar game with the category [$\mathbf{Ab}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ab) of abelian groups and group homomorphisms. Fix an abelian group $A$. Since there is only one morphism $\{0\}\to A$, we have to use a different domain than the trivial group, but it can still be done: elements $g\in A$ correspond to group homomorphisms $\bar g:\Bbb Z\to A$ (here, the correspondence has $\bar g(1):=g$). Therefore, we can think of morphisms $\varphi:A\to B$ as functions mapping "elements" $\Bbb Z\to A$ to "elements" $\Bbb Z\to B$.

In a general category $\mathcal C$, we can't expect that *exactly* this story works: there won't always exist some object $S\in\mathcal C$ so that elements of any $X\in\mathcal C$ correspond to morphisms $S\to\mathcal C$ (like I mentioned before, there isn't even a good reason to expect that objects of $\mathcal C$ *has* elements), but why restrict ourselves to just one object $S$? This is where the perspective of [generalised elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+element) comes to play: we can think of morphisms $S\to X$ as "$S$-shaped elements" of $X$.

Now, given an object $X$ and a morphism $f:X\to Y$, we can think of $f$ as a function of "$S$-shaped elements $x:S\to X$" into "$S$-shaped elements $f\circ x:S\to Y$", allowing ourselves to vary $S$ freely. This perspective can sometimes come in handy when looking at certain constructions and definitions in category theory: for example, a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is [monic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monomorphism) (the categorical analogue of "injective") if it is injective as a function of $S$-shaped elements in $X$ for all $S$: given $x,y:S\to X$, if $f\circ x=f\circ y$, then $x=y$.

This is also a helpful perspective for [limits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/limit). For example, given two objects $X$ and $Y$, their product is the object $X\times Y$ such that for any pair of $S$-shaped elements $x:S\to X$ and $y:S\to Y$, there is a unique $S$-shaped element $(x,y):S\to X\times Y$ whose components are $x$ and $y$. This reveals how the categorical product corresponds to the Cartesian product in $\mathbf{Set}$!

Finally, I want to mention that this perspective is not magical, but is really a way of interpreting the [Yoneda embedding](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+embedding): you can think of an object $X\in\mathcal C$ as an $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal C)$-indexed collection of "sets" $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(S,X)$ (the set of $S$-shaped elements in $X$), and in this way, a morphism $X\to Y$ is an $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal C)$-indexed collection of "functions" $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(S,f):\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(S,X)\to\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(S,Y)$.

Comment: Just a typo on your last paragraph : You can think of an object $X\in\mathcal{C} $ as a $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$-indexed collection of sets.

Comment: oh my, you're right! Thanks